# What are the elements of this clause?

Tags: parts-of-speech, clauses, syntactic-analysis

I am unsure whether I am identifying the elements in the following clause correctly.

> Phobias often originate from traumatic experiences in one's childhood

I am parsing this as follows.

| Element | Part of speech |
| --- | --- |
| Phobias | subject |
| Often | adverbial of frequency |
| Originate | verb |
| From traumatic experiences | adverbial of place |
| In one's childhood | adverbial of time |

Is this correct?

Comment: Can't they (from traumatic experiences'  and 'in one's childhood') be considered prepositional phrases?

Comment: "in one's childhood" modifies the noun phrase "traumatic experiences". it is not an adverbial of time.

Comment: It's slightly ambiguous (English allows a fair amount of latitude in where to place adverbials, and speakers are often careless about what rules exist), but fev offers the most plausible reading. If it was the origination happening in childhood rather than the traumatic experiences, you would probably say "phobias often originate in one's childhood from traumatic experiences".

Comment: Not quite: the PP "from traumatic experiences" is not modifier of "originate" but  **complement**. The PP "In one's childhood" is a modifier of "traumatic experiences". Adjuncts (adverbials) modify verbs etc, but not nouns.